# How to filter on column names in R

Tags: r

I would like to make a subset of a data frame in R that is based on multiple column names.

Example:

```
colnames <- c("RecentAVsB","RecentAMinusB","Label","TeamA","TeamB","Venue")
```

From this I would like to extract features those has "AVsB" or "AMinusB" or "Label" only. And these AvsB and AMinusB are multiple times, so don't want to extract using name. I tried..

```
myvars <-  grep("AMinusB" | "AVsB" | "Label", names(df), ignore.case=T)
```

But it gives error like:

```
Error in "AMinusB" | "AVsB" : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
```

What is the best way to select only those specific features.

Comment: Please read `help(grep)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern` argument in `grep` should be a single string i.e. enclosed by two double quotes (`""`) or single (`''`).

```
grep("AMinusB|AVsB|Label", names(df), ignore.case=T)
```